# PHP execute firefox to load webpage? e.g openlink.php?link=blah.com

Tags: php, firefox, load, exec, html

I want PHP to execute links on my PC from just loading a webpage on my phone.

I have an app that automatically detects youtube/music links in sms texts sent to me and loads the body of the text into a webpage as a variable (%body), so people can text me with a link that they want played on my PC.

http://localhost/openlink.php?link=http://www.google.com (or link=%body% from app)

openlink.php:

```
<?php

//Show the value of the variable "link" (Shows it every time)
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['link']);

 //Set $link
 $link = $_GET['link'];

//Open firefox in attempt to run the webpage stored in "link" (attempts to open $link.com)
exec(' "C:\Firefox\firefox.exe" "$link" ');
?>
```

The above currently works fine apart from one thing... it doesn't load $link as the variable... each time it is sending firefox to load http://www.$link.com/ instead of the text/link inside the variable

I've been searching around the net a lot however cannot find how I can get it to load the website that is in the variable

Could someone please help? Maybe I'm requiring code completely different in order to do this?

Comment: You need to fix your quotes.  Variables are only interpreted inside "double quotes".  `exec("C:\Firefox\firefox.exe $link");`

Comment: Nothing happens now when it's like that - nothing is executed

Comment: Hmm.. maybe the inner quotes are needed: `exec("'C:\Firefox\firefox.exe' '$link'");`

Comment: Giving me an Undefined variable error or if I put a link there, it just doesn't execute still. blank page / no error

Comment: DId you forget to set `$link` to something?  `$link = $_GET['link']`, maybe?

Comment: Removes the undeclared variable error - still nothing executed if the entire thing is together in double quotes :/ - and otherwise still loads $link.com

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work!

```
<?php

//Show the value of the variable "link"
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['link']);

//Set $link
$link = $_GET['link'];

//Open firefox in attempt to run the webpage stored in "link" 
exec(' "C:\Firefox\firefox.exe" " '.$link.' " ');

?>
```

Just by simply using '.$link.'